# Complete list of goals

Tags: google-analytics-api

When using Google Analytics API (management), we can use [Goals:list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/goals/list) endpoint to obtain list of Goal entities. However, I noticed this list does not include any Smart Goals.

In the UI, when we look at the Goals list, we see Smart Goal listed, and it is differentiated by goal type.

Is there a way to obtain list of Smart Goals separately?

If not, is there any workaround to be able to get list of all goals? (at least id and name)?

Please provide API calls and / or java lib (com.google.apis:google-api-services-analytics) sample, as there were some attempts to explain workaround but not in a clear way.

[image: list of all goals which shows smart goal is included]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I wish I had a better answer for you. Smart goals are  not supported in the API. There is a Feature Request about this issue on the Google Analytics API's issue tracker here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35353685

The only way I know of to get this information is in the UI.